# Is there any method to convert boolean variable to integer in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a ruby variable 'is_published'. I want to convert the value in 'is_published' to integer. Is there any method in ruby to do that?

```
if is_published == true
  is_published = 1
else
  is_published = 0
end
```

The above code works perfectly. Please help if there is any way to do this in a single line code.

Comment: May be like this: `is_published = is_published? 1: 0;` I don't know the syntax of ruby, I use this in js

Comment: You can use  the conditional operator(? :). "is_published ? 1 : 0" is answer for you.

Comment: `is_published = (is_published && 1) || (is_published || 0)` is another way.

Comment: That equals `(is_published && 1) || 0`, @CarySwoveland

Comment: @spickermann, yes, that's better. My preference: `is_published ? 1 : 0`. Boring, perhaps, but reads the best.

Comment: @RahulV : Can you explain why you need to do this? Because normally Rails does all the transformation of booleans to strings (in the view) or integers (in the db) for you. Perhaps there is a smarter way, if we know why you are doing this.

Comment: @spickermann : I was exporting all records in an active-record model to a CSV file. So in case of Boolean fields its written as 'true' or 'false'. I wanted to write it as 0 or 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class TrueClass; def to_i; 1; end; end
class FalseClass; def to_i; 0; end; end
```

Comment: Egad, Egor! That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: This is probably too global for my taste :)

Comment: Accepting this answer, but i would like to use                 is_published = (is_published && 1) || (is_published || 0)

Comment: I agree with @SergioTulentsev.  Is the reason for doing this that you're using a database which stores booleans as 0 & 1 (eg MySQL)?  If so then it would be better to hook into Rails' db "translators" to do this - then it will be db-agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

```rb
# using logical operators
is_published = is_published && 1 || 0

# using ternary operator
is_published = is_published ? 1 : 0
```