# How to display boolean results in terms of integer

Tags: ruby

I have the following array

```
a = []
```

When I call a.empty? It will return true. 
But I want the same result in Numeric that is 1(In ruby 1 means true and 0 means false).

I know one scenario by using ternary operator

```
a.empty? ? 1 : 0
```

I want the same result without using any operators or if else conditions.

Comment: your scenario is the simplest way

Comment: Also, just [three days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396547/is-there-any-method-to-convert-boolean-variable-to-integer-in-ruby#comment43240945_27396547).

Answer (score 0):

> > In ruby 1 means true and 0 means false

This is simply not true (pun intended). `0` is true as well as 1. Try it out.

The only falsy values in ruby are `nil` and `false` - that's it. So, an empty string is true, empty array is true, 0 is true etc.